# Restricting access to team work items in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

We have a project with over 100 teams. We have a tree structure for Area Path:

```
CompanyName  
    Division A
        Team A1
        Team A2
    Division B
        Team B1
        Team B2
```

We have a contractor that needs access to Team B2's work items but no access to any other area path.
If I add the contractor to Team B2 then they have acccess to **all** work items in the project.
I want to restrict them to just Team B2's area path.

I think I can get this to work by **Deny ** access for the contractor to Division A's area path and Team B1 area path.
But, if I create a new team in Division B, say Team B3, I need to remember to change the security to deny the contractor from accessing Team B3

I would prefer to set it up so contractor has Allow access to Team B2 and no access anywhere else.
Can I do that and if so how?

Cheers

Comment: Permissions have three states: `Not set`, `Allow`, and `Deny`. Only `Allow` gives access. The same permission might be set to different states in different groups that the user is a member of and on the user account itself. When the states are different, `Allow` overrides `Not set` and `Deny` overrides both `Allow` and `Not set`. A team is a group. If the contractor is not added to the B3 team and doesn't belong to any other group with an `Allow` for the B3 area path, then the contractor will not have access.

Comment: See [Permission states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#permission-states).

Comment: If I add the contractor to B2 team and do nothing else then they have access to everything through the Contributor group. So do I add them to the B2 team or not?  If I add them to the B2 team do i have to deny them access to the whole tree structure except the B2 area path? Sorry but i am not sure how to set this up

Comment: You can create a `Contractor Team B2` group. For that group, on `Division A` set `Deny`. On `Division B` set `Deny`. On `Division B\Team B2` clear the inherited `Deny` and set `Allow`. In addition to `Contributors`, the contractor would be a member of the `Contractor Team B2` group. At a later time if a `Division B\Team B3` is created, it will inherit `Deny` from `Division B`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I have got it right but different from your suggestion above.  I created a group Contractor Team B2. I added the contractor to that group.  I did not add the contractor to Team B2, so they will not be in the normal Contributor group.  The group Contractor Team B2 I didn't put it into any security settings except for Team B2 where i gave it Allow access, so nothing in Division A or Divivsion B.  It seems to work.  Do you see any reason it shouldn't? Thank you

Comment: @johnedwards, it should work same, the point is you should `deny` permisison on parent node `Division A` and `Division B`(inheritance enabled), and `allow` permission on sub area `Team B2`. So that the when you create a new `Sub` area under `Division B`, team B2 account won't have permission due to inheritance for `Division B`. I add the details in the reply.

Comment: @johnedwards Sounds like that should work. You may find that there may be other permissions granted by the Contributors group that the contractor may need, but those permissions can be added to the Contractor Team B2 group.

Comment: Hi @johnedwards, may i know if there's any update?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Jonathan Dodds. The point is you need to deny permission on parent node `Division A` and `Division B`(and even `CompanyName` Area path), and `allow` on target sub area path `Team B2`. So that when you create new area path `Division B/Team B3`, the account doesn't have permission on the new area path due to inherit from parent `Division B`.

You can create a group `Contractor Team B2` or directly use `Team B2`.

[image]

Only Area Path `Team B2` work items can be accessed.

[image]